# std::vector<int[5]> Vec; Как правильно присвоить значения переменным?

Tags: c++

Не могу присвоить значения вектору из массивов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int[5]> Vec;
int main() {

    Vec.push_back({1,2,3,4,5}); //Вызывает ошибку
    Vec.at(0)[0] = 5; //Вызывает ошибку

    std::cout << Vec[0][1];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector< std::array<int,5> > Vec;
int main() {
    Vec.push_back({1,2,3,4,5}); //ok
    Vec.at(0)[0] = 5; //ok
    std::cout << Vec[0][1]; //ok
}
```

Comment: причину проблемы можно было-бы рассказать. что у простых массивов нет операции присваивания, не могут быть **r-value**, например.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Rvalue они могут быть, но через одно место. `using arr = int[]; arr{1,2,3};`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat всё-таки может быть массив r-value. передаётся спокойно r-ссылкой https://godbolt.org/z/za9df14Tb Остаётся только загвоздка отсутствия конструктора копирования.